# Outlook add-ins Event handler trigger when I open the Message in Outlook

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins, outlook-restapi

In outlook Message when i open and read the message trigger that event on my outlook add-ins , any handler is available for that ,

It is possible , when i read the message or click the message to open , i want to trigger action on my handler

Add-ins developed by using javascript language

any thoughts about this please share me

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the Outlook add-in framework supports OnNewMessageCompose and OnNewAppointmentOrganizer events as part of 1.10 API set.

Additionally, you refer to the [documentation for outlook events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/autolaunch). There are other events that are currently in preview.